# Screen goes blank white when logging out

Tags: html, jsp, jsf

I have this JSP project that I need to edit(not my own code,so I'm pretty confused). As of now, to display the project content,  there is a frameset in the file `e-system.html`, that contains the source `loginMenu.jsf`.

Everything works fine, except when I try to logout, the screen just turns to blank white, and I would need to refresh the page to go the intended logout screen. 
The URL resource that I type to access the website is : `../BIS/e-system.html`
But when I key in: `../BIS/loginMenu.jsf` it can logout totally fine.

I think the reason is because of this frameset. Is there any alternate way of solving this issue. I have put the necessary code that links the files to the `e-system.html` plus also my logout code just in case.

**web.xml** :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

**index.jsp** :

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%response.sendRedirect("e-system.html");%>
```

**e-system.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
<TITLE>E-System</TITLE>
</HEAD>
   <FRAMESET>
    <FRAME src="loginMenu.jsf">
</FRAMESET> 
</HTML>
```

**logout.jsp** :

```
 <%
        UserInfo uif = (UserInfo)session.getAttribute("UserInfo");
        if(uif!=null){
            uif.logout();
        }
        for (Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
            session.removeAttribute((String)e.nextElement());
        }
         session.invalidate(); 
         request.logout();
         response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());  
    %>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you use scriptlet code to perform the logout instead of doing it in a session bean, which is how JSF should work here?

Comment: This code was done quite some time ago, and was never really edited over the years. I know that we definitely should not be using scriplets nowadays. But coming back to my question, any ideas on the frame issue?